# How to add rows for missing combination of data and impute corresponding fields with 0

Tags: mysql, sql, pandas, pyspark, psql

I have combination of domain and month with their total orders in corresponding month. I would like to impute missing combination with 0 values. What's the least expensive aggregation commands that can be used in Pyspark to achieve this ?

I have following input table:

```
domain      month    year   total_orders
google.com  01       2017   20
yahoo.com   02       2017   30
google.com  03       2017   30
yahoo.com   03       2017   40
a.com       04       2017   50
a.com       05       2017   50
a.com       06       2017   50
```

Expected Output:

```
domain      month    year   total_orders
google.com  01       2017   20
yahoo.com   02       2017   30
google.com  03       2017   30
yahoo.com   03       2017   40
a.com       04       2017   50
a.com       05       2017   50
a.com       06       2017   50
google.com  02       2017   0
google.com  04       2017   0
yahoo.com   04       2017   0
google.com  05       2017   0
yahoo.com   05       2017   0
google.com  06       2017   0
yahoo.com   06       2017   0
```

Here Expected order of output does not really matter.

Comment: What have you tried so far in Pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to combine *all months and years* for each domain:

```
select my.year, my.month, d.domain, coalesce(t.total_orders, 0) as total_orders
from (select distinct month, year from input) my cross join
     (select distinct domain from input) d left join
     t
     on t.month = my.month and t.year = my.year and t.domain = d.domain;
```

Note:  This assumes that each year/month combination occurs at least once, somewhere in the data.

Getting values within a range is a pain because you have split the date into multiple columns.  Let me assume the years are all the same, as in your example:

```
select my.year, my.month, d.domain, coalesce(t.total_orders, 0) as total_orders
from (select distinct month, year from input) my join
     (select domain, min(month) as min_month, max(month) as max_month
      from input
     ) d
     on my.month >= d.min_month and my.month <= d.max_month left join
     t
     on t.month = my.month and t.year = my.year and t.domain = d.domain
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I will figure out how to manipulate these queries to use with Spark